# Compile node package as ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm working on a node package that is using webpack 4 and babel 7 to compile.

When I'm doing the following export on the package

```js
export default { foo: "bar" }
```

and I'm trying to import it using:

```js
import obj from "package"
```

`obj` get the default namespace, meaning `obj` looks like:

```js
{ default: { foo: "bar" } }
```

I've read the [following article](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-import-and-commonjs-d619d626b655) by webpack, and it says that non-ESM modules will now get the `default` namespace.

My question is, how can I compile my package in a way that generates an ESM module so I can import the default property normally?

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: [__dirname + "/src/index.js"],

  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },

  target: "node",

  mode: "production",

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },

  externals: externals.reduce(
    (acc, name) => Object.assign({}, acc, { [name]: true }),
    {}
  ),

  plugins: [
    new GenerateJsonPlugin("package.json", genPackage())
  ]
}
```

Comment: The article you link to is about dynamic import (`import()`), not static import, which is what you're using in the above. *"`obj` get the default namespace, meaning `obj` looks like: `{ default: { foo: "bar" } }`"* With the `export` and `import` statements in your question, any tool where `obj` ends up in that form is broken, violating the specification. What you've shown would be the result of `import * as obj from "package"`, not `import obj from "package"`. I find it hard to believe Webpack is doing that.

Comment: OMG, there was one inner import like that.. I can't believe it. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! Did I accidentally solve the problem? :-)